# Jenkins shows London GMT even if configured differently

Tags: jenkins

Our Jenkins server is located in Germany so that we want to see European time in Jenkins.

For this purpose we inserted the parameter `user.timezone="Europe/Berlin"` to Jenkins configuration.

After Jenkins start we do see the European time but after a while it switches to the London GMT and remains so.

Do you know this phenomenon? If so how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

To see what time zone your Jenkins is using, browse to:

http://servername:port/systemInfo

To change the Jenkins timezone, edit jenkins.xml in the Jenkins base directory, and add values to JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS on the following arguments: `-Duser.timezone` and `-Dorg.apache.commons.jelly.tags.fmt.timeZone`

For example:

> -Xrs -Xmx256m -Duser.timezone="Europe/Berlin"
>   -Dorg.apache.commons.jelly.tags.fmt.timeZone="Europe/Berlin" -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war" -httpPort=8080

Restart Jenkins.

Comment: That's exactly what's currently set in our `jenkins.xml` file: `<arguments>-Xrs -Xmx256m -Duser.timezone=”Europe/Berlin” -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -jar “%BASE%\jenkins.war” –httpPort=8080</arguments>`. Despite this correct timezone setting Jenkins displays the GMT time, not immediately after start but first after a certain time. Why? Is there any plugin that could manipulate the time set at start?

Comment: don't know, maybe.. if you will find the answear.. don't forget to public it